# The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library on shared drive after silently updating Equinox launcher

Tags: eclipse, windows-10, eclipse-neon

I have Eclipse installed on a removable drive that I take between my desktop and laptop. I have an old installation (Mars) that I installed ages ago by unzipping files. I have a newer installation (Neon) that I installed using the new Eclipse installer.

After upgrading both my computers to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, both Eclipse installations continue to work when the drive is connected to the desktop machine. When I connect the drive to the laptop, however, the new Eclipse installation (Neon---the one installed using the installer) will not start and says:

```
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
```

However the old installation (Mars---the one installed from unzipping an archive) still runs just fine.

What is the problem with the Neon installation on the laptop and how do I fix it?

*Update:* I looked in the `eclipse.ini` file, and there is a `--launcher.library` reference to a `C:/Users/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444`. The laptop (which is failing) has only `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417`. But the desktop (where it is working) has both `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417` and `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444`.

So maybe somehow Eclipse updated its Equinox Launcher when the drive was attached to the desktop. Then when I attached the drive to the laptop, it referenced the updated launcher plugin, but the laptop didn't have the updated launcher.

This is a fine kettle of fish. I had no idea Eclipse was installing things in the user directory, outside the Eclipse installation directory. I guess that's one of the drawbacks of this newfangled launcher: it's not possible to use Eclipse on a shared drive.

How can I get Eclipse to install the launcher on the shared drive rather than in the system user home directory? Can I avoid this altogether if I install directly from zip files? How did Eclipse update this launcher in the first place without my knowing about it?

*Update*: Now I see that Eclipse also installed a `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar` in the *local* `plugins` directory (that is, relative to the executable on the drive). Why is Eclipse putting some things on the removable drive relative to the executable (as they should be), and other things in the system user directory (where I don't want them)? This is a mess. So much for having a self-contained Eclipse installation like I did for over a decade.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is on the removable drive? Does your user login still own the directory tree? Does it still have the Read and Execute permissions on the Security tab?

Comment: The drive uses NTFS. Administrators have full control of the entire drive. The user on each machine is an administrator. Nothing has changed with this configuration for years---except Windows has updated to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition on both machines.

Comment: So maybe I would get somewhere if you could tell me exactly what "companion shared library" Eclipse is looking for?

Comment: I don't know specifically myself. I've just seen it happen when the .exe or one of the .dll files buried in the plugins or configuration folder was not marked as Executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Eclipse installer does use a shared "bundle pool" so that if you have multiple different Eclipse instances running, the various plugins they're using are only downloaded once. This usually saves network bandwidth and disk space.
However, this bundle pool may probably be unable to work properly if the installation and bundle pool are on different drive (Especially if one of them is shared by multiple machines). You can report this limitation to http://bugs.eclipse.org .

As a workaround, for such custom installations, I would recommend that you skip the Eclipse installer, and get good old packages that will work just like Mars, everything in their own directory: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Comment: So if I decide to install a standalone Eclipse from a zip file, how do I get rid of the "bundle pool"? Can I just wipe out the `~user/.p2/pool/` directory? What about the `~user/.p2/` directory itself?

Comment: If you go for packages instead of installer, yes, you should be able to wipe out  this ~/.p2 directory.